# Why use multi-stage build for netcore applications?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

By default, dotnet core projects create a multi-stage build Dockerfile in which the application's source code is copied into a temporary container, built and published there, and then copied to a smaller runtime container as the final image.

I built an image this way, and then with a much simpler Dockerfile in which I pulled only the aspnetcore runtime image and then copied in the already-published application from my development machine.  This produced an image I'm able to run on Docker Desktop.  The size of the two images is exactly the same.

The direct-copy Dockerfile is much simpler than the multi-stage build file and eliminates the need for me to jump through some hoops so that the build inside the intermediate Docker container is able to see some custom resources that need to be pulled in.

Why is the multi-stage build used instead of simply copying the published application in the runtime folder?  Are there scenarios in which the resulting image will not run correctly?

Comment: The main reason is for develop in the continuous integration mode, think to building the app from GitHub or DevOps, you must automate the entire process.

Comment: @Max: Even in CI mode, you could build on the CI box and not in a container.  In fact, I found a previous question on this subject in which someone went back to build locally and single-stage containerization because it fit *better* into CI/CD.  Just as easy to automate a build locally.  Plus, ease of CI is never stated in docs as the reason for multi-stage; it's always about container size.

Comment: If you keep the build in `docker` then you can afford to lose your build server or to migrate to any other server that has `docker` installed on it.